# How to find 4 geodesic on a surface $z=xy$ passing through point (1,0,0)

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Let $S: z=xy$ be a surface
How can i find 4 geodesic on S passing throught a point (1,0,0) ?

I have already got $(t,0,0)$ and $(1,t,t)$ but i dont know how to find 2 other, any suggestion?

Comment: @ThePhenotype: Your first one doesn't go through $(1,0,0)$, evidently. And we don't call a "trivial geodesic" a geodesic; geodesics must have nonzero constant speed by every definition I know.

Comment: @TedShifrin Woops, I didn't check that one :( But the "trivial geodesic" $(1,0,0)$ is one according to the definition on wikipedia, am I right? (Not the best source, but it even agrees with the definition in Thorpe's ETIDM)